# Replace all images to be element's own id + .jpg

Tags: jquery

What is a good way to replace all background-images on certain elements, to be each element's own id + ".jpg"? Using jquery

Do I need to use $.each, or can I edit this to work somehow:

```
$(".element").css("background-image", "url(img/" + $(this).data("id") + ".jpg)");
// it sets undefined.jpg, $(this) is not the way
```

EDIT PS: data("id") is not a typo/mistake. I use data.id on the element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can the setter version of [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) that takes a [function as the second argument](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) and then return the style value from that function

```
$(".element").css("background-image", function () {
    return "url(img/" + $(this).data("id") + ".jpg)"
});
```

In your case `this` will refer to the function's context in which you have written the code, instead you need to have a reference to the current `.element` element.

Comment: @mowgli it will be better if you can modify the html to have the inline css without depending on script, but if you have to then it is a fine approach

Comment: Yes ok. Well, I had inline css before, but I need to use jquery instead. And the site depends on javascript anyway so it's ok

Comment: Theres small mistake. You need to use .attr('id'), not .data('id')

Comment: @vishwanath No ;) I'm using data-id on the element, not id

Comment: @vishwanath, only if he meant using the elements ID. In his question it looks like using an ID from jQuery's data store or the elements data-attr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each() for this.

```
$( ".element" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(img/" + $(this).attr("id") + ".jpg)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use each method if there are more than one elements.

```
$(".element").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(img/" + $(this).attr("id") + ".jpg)");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.element').each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).css("background-image", "url(img/" + $(element).attr('id') + ".jpg)");
});
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, showing what id does and how it solves the problem - this will help others who see your answer in the future